# Clickable content in $ionicLoading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a clickable button inside $ionicLoading(template). I want to run some code if that button is clicked. Unfourtunately ng-click doesnt seem to work. Any work around? or am i making a fatal assumption. PS:Im a newbie at angular and ionic

```
  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><br /><br /><p>Syncronising...</p>'
  });

       //stopSync function never fires
       $scope.stopSync = function(){
          $ionicLoading.hide();
       }

  //Shows the 'stop Sync' Button after two seconds 
  //for the user to fire the stopSync function
  $timeout(function() {
     $ionicLoading.show({
       template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><br /><br /><p>Syncronising...</p><button class="button button-clear" ng-click="stopSync()">Stop Sync</button>'
     });
  }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue thanks to http://atomx.io/2015/01/ionic-closing-ionicloading-if-your-app-loses-network-connectivity/

I had to add a `scope: $scope` as part of the parameters

```
$ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><br /><br /><p>Syncronising...</p>'
          });


          $timeout(function() {
             //$ionicLoading.hide();
             $ionicLoading.show({
               template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><br /><br /><p>Syncronising...</p><button class="button button-clear" ng-click="stopSync()">Stop Sync</button>',
               scope: $scope
             });
          }, 2000);

 $scope.stopSync = function(){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
 };
```